# Background color for two cells in the same row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

This code is to color one cell which I use

```
If Cells(1, Target.Column) = "Red" Then

   Sheet1.Range(Target.Cells.address).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

I want the cells of column F colored too if that cell is colored.

Comment: What are the two columns? One if "F". What is the other?

Comment: @SiddharthRout column K

Comment: @SiddharthRout  the first cell of column K has value "Red" so I use Target.Column

Comment: So just to be clear. the moment you type say "Red" in K10, F10 should turn red?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I have a sheet has many columns all column has a declaration in cell 1 ex. ( A1: blue ) , (B1 : age )...etc , column K has a declaration "Red" and when I add any value to colmn cells      > it's backcolor will be red ( now I want two column be red when it it has a value

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: `when it it has a value` What has a value? Any column? You need to be specific.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `conditional formatting` for this task?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I want add a pic to clear for you but I can't becuse I need 10 reputation , may you give me your email to send it for you

Comment: you can upload it in wikisend.com or any other file sharing site and share the link here?

Comment: @SiddharthRout this is the link http://wikisend.com/download/759508/red.png I hope it is clear for you

Comment: @lowak what shall I do ):

Comment: So whenever you enter a value in cell K, the color of cell K and F should be changed? Or when you change the color of cell K then the color of cell F should also change. which one is it?

Comment: @SiddharthRout see , column K is empty when I add any value to any cell in it its back color will be red ( look at the pic just the cell which has a value is colored ) now , I want when I add a value to cell in column K colored two cell not one (n the first one which I add a value in it in column K and the second one the cell in column F in the same row

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Iowak. Try `=$K1<>""` in CF with Use a formula to determine which cells to format and Format values where this formula is true and Applies to `=$K:$K,$F:$F` with red fill.